# spring mvc HTTP Status 404 basic start

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

i am not able to figure out what is the issue in this code. I am not getting the home page and also no error is shown in console.

web.xml:

```
<web-app>
    <display-name>Myapp</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml :

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.sim.market.controller" />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Home controller :

```
package com.sim.market.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/home")
public class HomeController {

    public String showHome(){
        System.out.println("calloing");
        return "home";
    }
}
```

on console no error but in browser error is

```
HTTP Status 404 -

type Status report

message

description The requested resource is not available.
```

[image]
Can anyone help me out? thanks in advance.

when run application from eclipse it shows following log:

```
Apr 03, 2014 6:54:30 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/i386/client:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/i386::/usr/java/packages/lib/i386:/lib:/usr/lib
Apr 03, 2014 6:54:30 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:MarketApp' did not find a matching property.
Apr 03, 2014 6:54:30 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Apr 03, 2014 6:54:30 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Apr 03, 2014 6:54:30 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 960 ms
Apr 03, 2014 6:54:30 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Apr 03, 2014 6:54:30 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.37
Apr 03, 2014 6:54:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt is already defined
Apr 03, 2014 6:54:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core is already defined
Apr 03, 2014 6:54:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt_rt is already defined
Apr 03, 2014 6:54:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt is already defined
Apr 03, 2014 6:54:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/standard/permittedTaglibs is already defined
Apr 03, 2014 6:54:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/standard/scriptfree is already defined
Apr 03, 2014 6:54:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql_rt is already defined
Apr 03, 2014 6:54:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql is already defined
Apr 03, 2014 6:54:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml_rt is already defined
Apr 03, 2014 6:54:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml is already defined
Apr 03, 2014 6:54:31 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(/home/webwerks/sachin/workspaces/sedi_workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/MarketApp/WEB-INF/lib/servlet-api-3.0-alpha-1.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Apr 03, 2014 6:54:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt is already defined
Apr 03, 2014 6:54:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core is already defined
Apr 03, 2014 6:54:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core is already defined
Apr 03, 2014 6:54:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt_rt is already defined
Apr 03, 2014 6:54:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt is already defined
Apr 03, 2014 6:54:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt is already defined
Apr 03, 2014 6:54:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions is already defined
Apr 03, 2014 6:54:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/standard/permittedTaglibs is already defined
Apr 03, 2014 6:54:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/standard/scriptfree is already defined
Apr 03, 2014 6:54:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql_rt is already defined
Apr 03, 2014 6:54:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql is already defined
Apr 03, 2014 6:54:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql is already defined
Apr 03, 2014 6:54:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml_rt is already defined
Apr 03, 2014 6:54:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml is already defined
Apr 03, 2014 6:54:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml is already defined
Apr 03, 2014 6:54:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt is already defined
Apr 03, 2014 6:54:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core is already defined
Apr 03, 2014 6:54:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt_rt is already defined
Apr 03, 2014 6:54:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt is already defined
Apr 03, 2014 6:54:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/standard/permittedTaglibs is already defined
Apr 03, 2014 6:54:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/standard/scriptfree is already defined
Apr 03, 2014 6:54:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql_rt is already defined
Apr 03, 2014 6:54:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql is already defined
Apr 03, 2014 6:54:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml_rt is already defined
Apr 03, 2014 6:54:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml is already defined
Apr 03, 2014 6:54:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt is already defined
Apr 03, 2014 6:54:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core is already defined
Apr 03, 2014 6:54:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core is already defined
Apr 03, 2014 6:54:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt_rt is already defined
Apr 03, 2014 6:54:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt is already defined
Apr 03, 2014 6:54:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt is already defined
Apr 03, 2014 6:54:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions is already defined
Apr 03, 2014 6:54:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/standard/permittedTaglibs is already defined
Apr 03, 2014 6:54:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/standard/scriptfree is already defined
Apr 03, 2014 6:54:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql_rt is already defined
Apr 03, 2014 6:54:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql is already defined
Apr 03, 2014 6:54:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql is already defined
Apr 03, 2014 6:54:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml_rt is already defined
Apr 03, 2014 6:54:38 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml is already defined
Apr 03, 2014 6:54:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml is already defined
Apr 03, 2014 6:54:39 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Apr 03, 2014 6:54:39 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Apr 03, 2014 6:54:39 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Apr 03, 2014 6:54:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 8143 ms
```

and when i call the resource like home.do
it shows :

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Apr 03, 2014 6:56:09 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher'
```

Comment: What URL are you using to access your resource? And is your web app deployed properly on your web server and is your web server up and running?

Comment: http://localhost:8080/MyApp/home.do

Comment: I didn't see the url what @coreJavare was calling. Removing my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Well you should add this in web.xml

```
<welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
   </welcome-file-list>
```

add this snippet to index.jsp

```
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="0; url=${pageContext.request.contextPath}/home.do">
```

I found this as a good option every time I make application in Spring mvc

Comment: What will this change?

Comment: First it will be  redirected to the index.jsp page that will get refresh and redirect to the URL you specify...And this URl should be the mapping of the controller method you want to execute

Comment: @coreJavare : Pls check the slf4j configuration..it may be jar issue of slf4j..version problem may be there

Comment: But they were already sending the request to a proper URI, so what does going through a different page first get them?

Answer (score 0):

Annotate your `showHome()` method with `@RequestMapping` to identify it as a handler. Without it your controller has no handler methods and therefore nothing to handle the request with.

Obviously, you add restrictions on the `@RequestMapping`, like which HTTP methods are handled, which headers it might contain, or even specialize the path that should be handled.

Comment: just done the same added : 
 @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)  but still same error

Comment: @core Is your application deployed? What do the logs show?

Comment: please check the question as i have added description for log

Comment: @core As an aside, consider fixing your logging. It'll pretty much tell you exactly what went wrong. Right now your slf4j configuration seems wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You need mapping for your requests.

```
@RequestMapping (value = "/showhome", method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST})
public String showHome(ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest request) { }
```

Like that.

Comment: your request should be localhost/ProjectName/home/showHome